# Downloading own-forked repo from gradle - still downloads not mine

Tags: android, github, gradle

Let's say that there is a repo:
https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/

I need to make changes and pull it to Android Studio so I forked this to mine repo, made changes and made a release with a tag 'kryofix1':
https://github.com/Magic-WoW/kryonet/releases

I use jitpack for downloading this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile "com.github.Magic-WoW:kryonet:kryofix1"
}
```

**It still downloads files from the first repo, I can't see changes in downloaded files (but when I download zip from releases - they are there - these mine changes)**

What's wrong?

## edit :

```
# Temporary Files
*~
.*.swp
.DS_STORE

bin/
target/
.idea/
*.iml
```

Comment: check if your gitignore has gradle.build ingored or not. If ignored, remove it from list.

Comment: Added git-ignore to edit. It's okay

There is no info about gradle. Btw, it synchronizes perfectly on android studio, but when I go to External Libraries and open any file, there are no changes - it's a clean Kryonet from the first repo...